# VHDL - How to add 1 to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR?

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- entity part contain R for output of Register
    
entity register_16 is
    port(   input:  in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        ld, inc, clk, clr:  in std_logic;
        R: buffer std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end register_16 ;

-- it have to parallel process    

architecture behavioral of register_16 is
begin


reg: process (input, ld, clk, clr)
    variable R_temp: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin
    if (clr = '1') then
        R_temp := b"0000000000000000";
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        if (ld = '1') then
            R_temp := input;
        end if;
    end if;
    R <= R_temp;
end process reg;

-- my error in this step    

inc_R: process (inc)
begin
    R <= R + '1';
end process inc_R;

end behavioral;
```

Main process (reg) works correctly, but other process has error adding 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to say, but there are quite a lot of things wrong with your code...

1. You are mixing combinatorial and sequential code in the same process, which is poor coding style. If coded correctly, there really is no need for the variable R_temp.
2. The sensitivity list is a simulation aid only, yet you are trying to use it as a conditional (when inc changes, increment R). This will not work in hardware. When starting out with VHDL, my suggestion is to use VHDL_2008 and always use process(all) as the sensitivity list. This avoids beginner errors, since it reflects what synthesis does.
3. You are creating a combinatorial loop in the second process. This will not show up in simulation because of 2. above, but will cause errors in synthesis.
4. As already mentioned by baldyHDL, you are assigning to R in multiple processes.
5. Prefer unsigned to std_logic_vector when dealing with numbers. Generally you should not include std_logic_arith, nor std_logic_unsigned, just std_logic_1164 and numeric_std.
6. Adding a std_logic value (such as '1') is not standard, or at least not supported by all tools. Simply use an integer instead: `R <= R + 1;`

By your code, I gather that you are trying to write a counter with increment, load and clear signals. I don't just want to give you the code (that would ruin the learning experience for you), but try to fit the entire counter into a single process, using the following template:

```
process(clk) begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        -- Your code here vvv
        if(clr = '1') then

        elsif(ld = '1') then

        elsif(inc = '1') then

        end if;
        -- Your code here ^^^
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: From #6, "use an integer instead" a better alternative is often use `unsigned` from `ieee.numeric_std`. This lets you keep `std_logic` semantics and also lets you use big values like `unsigned(127 downto 0)` which you can't do with integers.

Comment: @wjl I meant the integer 1, not R. The OP was trying to add a std_logic_vector and a std_logic, which isn't allowed. Given 5., it's possible to add the integer 1 to R.

Comment: I agree that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 15):

You will have to convert the vector to an integer an back again, here's an example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

signal in  : std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0 );
signal out : std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0 );

out <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(to_integer(unsigned( in )) + 1, 8));
```

For a good picture about type conversion take a look here:

http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/vhdl-type-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

you write R in both of your processes. this leads to a multi-driver situation that is not possible to synthesise. to solve it, combine the processes, e.g.:

```
reg: process (clk, clr)
  variable R_temp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin
   if (clr='1') then
       R_temp := b"0000000000000000";
   elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
       if (ld='1') then
           R_temp := input;
       elsif (inc='1') then
           R_temp := R_temp + '1';
       end if;
   end if;
   R <= R_temp;
end process reg;
```

Comment: I'd also use `numeric_std` and make `R_temp` and `R` `unsigned` vectors

Comment: I don't think addition between R_temp and '1' is allowed.

Comment: There is no need for R_temp here. It just makes the process more complicated and leads to errors. Avoid variables if at all possible (and avoid them unconditionally when starting out with HDL), since variables lead to a sequential coding mindset, which is exactly what HDL is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a vector containing the value 1 as this, as you are using the numeric_std library:

```
R <= R + x"0001";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following libraries and it was able to do something similar

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

...

```
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);


begin
    process(clk, reset, ce, cnt)
        begin
            if(reset = '1') then
                cnt <= "0000";
            elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then 
                if(ce='1') then
                    if(cnt = "1001") then
                        cnt <= "0000";
                    else
                        cnt <= cnt + 1;
```